# android and gradle - where is the source to the build tasks?

Tags: android, gradle

Im trying to figure out how all of android's gradle build tasks work and Ive found the open source project online but digging through it hasnt really shed much light on how each task for a project works.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/6d7fd0d2eff092abf1aaf44d03756b24570b390c/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F

For example I would love to know the exact script it would take to replicate assemble or package and within those I would like to know exactly how to replicate any their child tasks.

Does documentation like this exist anywhere or are developers expected to bang their heads against the computer screen cursing gradle's creators for hours on end while they figure things out on their own.

And please resist the urge to leave a "read the manual" answer unless you leave a link pointing to what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any documentation which would outline what I really wanted but over the last few days I put it all together from reading Gradles documentation and doing a lot of debugging. It would be nice if in the future there was clear documentation on all the steps in one place so others dont have to spend days to figure things out.